# static runnable in Activity

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-handler, android-memory

I am modifying the following code in my activity:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
    txtStatus.setText("hello");
  }
}, 1000);
```

to:

```
static Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   txtStatus.setText("hello");
};

new Handler().postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
```

Which obviously doesn't work, since we're referencing a non static variable.

This doesn't work either:

```
public void setText() {
  txtStatus.setText("hello");
}
static Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   setText(); // doesn't work
   MyActivity.this.setText(); // still doesn't work

};

new Handler().postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
```

so how would my initial example be rewritten to use a static class instead of an anonymous inner class (to avoid the potential of a memory leak)?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to mark correct answers in your previous questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        txtStatus.setText("hello");
    }
};

// somewhere in code
txtStatus.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);

// in onPause or onDestroy
txtStatus.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Notes:

- this avoids memory leaks, as your `run` will never be called after `onDestroy` if you call `removeCallbacks`
- I replaced `new Handler()` with `txtStatus`, because every `View` has its own instance of `Handler` and there is no need to create additional one

Answer (score 5):

You can use WeakReference to avoid memory leak problems. Here is some code, which illustrate this idea

```
public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private WeakReference<Activity> activityRef;

    public MyRunnable(Activity activity) {
        activityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    public void run() {
         //some code
    }
}

private MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(this);
```

Comment: Using `WeakReference` doesn't help too much.

Comment: It doesn't stop the memory leak. After `Activity` is destroyed, `WeakReference` can still return you a strong reference to it.

Comment: Well I am not agree with you, if there are no other strong references to the activity, it won't return you a strong reference. You should check the documentation.

Comment: Weakly reachable objects will finally be collected, but it is not specified when and certainly it won't happen at the point in time they become weakly reachable.

Comment: Yes, but there is really no problems with that. If you worry about calling activity after onDestroy, you can raise a flag in onDestroy method and check it when you get a reference. Otherwise it doesn't matter that there exist a WeakReference, Activity would be garbage collected normally when it should.